# jQuery accordion and slider not working together

Tags: jquery, slider, accordion

We have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/c5cpk/

Which should show an accordion with content in each pane along with a jquery slider.

At the moment it doesn't it just show's the controls.

If you edit the CSS line:

```
#accordion .pane {  display:none;  height:705px; color:#fff; font-size:12px; }
```

and take away the `display:none` you will see the panes expanded and the slideshows work correctly.

Could anyone help me out as getting quite frustrated with the way it's (not) working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by assigning the display none after the page had loaded using:

```
jQuery('#accordion div.pane').css('display', 'none');
```